# What am I doing wrong with TextToSpeech

Tags: android

I have text to speech all set up here (or so I think) but when I go to press the button on my application it just closes and does not speak what I type in, (Now I was wondering if this is because I have not set up an OnClickListener event.  The reason why is because I really do know how to set up the OnClickListener event with teh TextToSpeach, So if that is the reason why My app isnt speaking then can someone direct me to a tutorial in this area that will help.  If its not the reason why, then can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
    package com.write.it;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener;  
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Speech extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener {
    private EditText words = null;
    private Button speakBtn = null;
        private static final int REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "TTS Demo";
        private TextToSpeech mTts;

        private int uttCount = 0;
        private HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        words = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordsToSpeak);
        speakBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);

       // Check to be sure that TTS exists and is okay to use
       Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
       checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
       startActivityForResult(checkIntent, REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK);
       }

   public void doSpeak(View view) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(words.getText().toString(),",.");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
                String.valueOf(uttCount++));
        mTts.speak(st.nextToken(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
     }
   }

   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (requestCode == REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS:
            // TTS is up and running
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            Log.v(TAG, "Pico is installed okay");
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_BAD_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_VOLUME:
            // missing data, install it
            Log.v(TAG, "Need language stuff: " + resultCode);
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL:
        default:
            Log.e(TAG, "Got a failure. TTS not available");
        }
    }
    else {
        // Got something else
    }
}

public void onInit(int status) {
    // Now that the TTS engine is ready, we enable the button
    if( status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        speakBtn.setEnabled(true);
        mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    // if we're losing focus, stop talking
    if( mTts != null)
        mTts.stop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mTts.shutdown();
}

public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Got completed message for uttId: " + uttId);
    Integer.parseInt(uttId);
}
    }
```

new code

```
    package com.write.it;

   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.StringTokenizer;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
   import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
   import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Speech extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener {
private EditText words = null;
private Button speakBtn = null;
     private static final int REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK = 0;
  private static final String TAG = "TTS Demo";
     private TextToSpeech mTts;

private int uttCount = 0;
private HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    words = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordsToSpeak);
    speakBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);
    mTts = new TextToSpeech(this,
            this);  // TextToSpeech.OnInitListener


       // Check to be sure that TTS exists and is okay to use
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK);
      }



      public void doSpeak(View view) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(words.getText().toString(),",.");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
                String.valueOf(uttCount++));
        mTts.speak(st.nextToken(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
     }
    speakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // /TODO Auto-generated method stub
            doSpeak(v);

        }
     });

      }

     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS:
            // TTS is up and running
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            Log.v(TAG, "Pico is installed okay");
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_BAD_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_VOLUME:
            // missing data, install it
            Log.v(TAG, "Need language stuff: " + resultCode);
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL:
        default:
            Log.e(TAG, "Got a failure. TTS not available");
        }
    }
    else {
        // Got something else
      }
      }

     public void onInit(int status) {
    // Now that the TTS engine is ready, we enable the button
    if( status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
    }
   }

   @Override
   public void onPause()
    {
    super.onPause();
    // if we're losing focus, stop talking
    if( mTts != null)
        mTts.stop();
   }

     @Override
           public void onDestroy()
   {
        super.onDestroy();
         mTts.shutdown();
        }

     public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Got completed message for uttId: " + uttId);
    Integer.parseInt(uttId);
     }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write TTS speak method in doSpeak() method. And you don't even call this method doSpeak(). Then how do you expect to speak it.

Set a listener in speak button and call doSpeak() in the listener. If still it don't speak, let me know.

Comment: ok Ill give it a try thank you, and it was my first time doing textToSpeech so I was completely unsure of everything

Comment: i am just getting a force close every time I press my button

Comment: In your new code i didnt see ant tts speak related thing. In you last code do this, speakBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     doSpeak(v);
    }
          
         });

Comment: its not speaking, i and I did it exactly how you said

Comment: public void doSpeak(View v) {
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(words.getText().toString(),",.");
  while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
      params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
                    String.valueOf(uttCount++));
   mTts.speak(st.nextToken(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
   speakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // /TODO Auto-generated method stub
     doSpeak(v);
   
  }
  });
      }